# Texdoc and the various files

Tags: expl3, documentation

Have been looking at `texdoc` and have found

```
texdoc interface3
texdoc source3
```

One of the documents states that it is a reference manual, the other that it is a reference documentation, for the L3 Programming Layer.  What is going on ?  It would help if there introduction was more explicit about what they are about and how the information was made or extracted.

Comment: They do not state that. source3 states and is the documented source.  expl3 states and is an "introduction" and interface3 states and is a reference manual

Comment: This is unrelated to the texdoc tag. texdoc simply shows the documentation available, the texdoc maintainers have no control overthe words.

Comment: `source3.pdf` says it is the reference documentation for the expl3 programming environment.  A document intended to act as a comprehensive reference manual for the expl3 language. Nothing about what is meant by source.  `interface3.pdf` says it is the reference documentation for the expl3 programming environment.  What is going on ?

Comment: well source3 says it's the reference documentation (of the _source_)  but I don't see any confusion here.  source2e is the source of latex in a similar way, not the latexbook, tex.web is the source of tex, not the texbook.

Comment: Why would you expect the documentation of a programming language to be the same file as the documentation of the source code of that language? Would you expect the source code of gcc to be in a reference manual for C ? actually source3 covers all of what is in interface3 as interface3 is just the interface parts, both are extracted from the dtx files

Comment: source3 should not say it's the reference documentation. (of the source) should not be implied automatically.  Where is it explained what documentation of the source is ?  Documentation is always about the source, or is it not ?

Comment: No tex has a tradition (used for tex itself) of literate programming (a term coined by Knuth) in which the primary file is a _document_ and the source code is mechanically extracted from that document (as opposed to systems that extract documentation from source comments)

Comment: and absolutely not. documentation is usually not about the source at all: it's about _use_. the latex book, interface3, the texbook, ... say _nothing_ about how those systems are implemented, they describe how they are _used_. If you get documentation of the java language you would expect to be told how to write a java program, not how to write a Java interpreter (in C)

Comment: You have edited the question since I answered it, but it is still false.  both describe themselves as "reference documentation" in the abstract and "reference manual" in chapter 1.  In both cases the whole text is identical typeset from the same source. Interface3 is the interface (only) description extracted from source3.  So all the words are the same (we could look to adding a note to the interface3 abstract so it says it's a subset of source3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any confusion or contradiction here. The filenames are a bit arbitrary and have historical issues, but the three files are quite natural.

source3 is the typeset source of expl3 (just as source2e is the documented source of latex2e, or tex-the-program is a documented source  tex.web, the source code of tex).

interface3 is the reference programming manual for expl3, extracted from the same dtx files as the above, but just listing the progamming interface and description of each callable command, without  the implementation sources or internal commands.

expl3 does not (despite your assertion) claim to be a reference manual: it's a general introduction to the system.

---

`interface3` is thus a subset of `source3` without the implementation sources typeset. This is explicit in the source

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This document typesets the LaTeX3 interface descriptions a single document.
% This produces quite a large file (more than 170 pages currently).
%
% There is also a full version of the sources (source3.tex) which additionally
% also typesets the command implementations.
%
```

But currently the abstract is simply extracted in the same way in both files so is identical text, we could look at having a modified abstract for interface3 saying, as in the comments, that it is the interface subset of the source3 document.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148884/discussion-on-answer-by-david-carlisle-texdoc-and-the-various-files); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.